# Compare strings in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

How to compare two strings and list of character values

```
l=['s','t','a','k','','o','v','e','r']
s='stack over'
```

how to compare the content(list and s).
if both are equal it has to return 'zero' if one is greater than other then return positive one is lesser than other then negative value 
I want to compare above list 'l' and string 's'
please tell me the how to do it with python code..

Comment: if this is for sorting, you shouldn't use `cmp()`

Answer (score 7):

```
l=['s','t','a','k','','o','v','e','r']
s='stack over'

cmp(l, list(s))
```

returns -1 because `l` is greater than `s` (the fourth position's `k` in `l` is greater than `c` in `s`)

```
l=['s','t','a','c', 'k',' ','o','v','e','r']
s='stack over'

cmp(l, list(s))
```

returns 0 as they are "equal".

Answer (score 5):

Or

```
>>> l=['s','t','a','k','','o','v','e','r']
>>> s='stack over'
>>> cmp(''.join(l), s)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cmp` function for this. To compare 2 items, both must be same type so you can try

```
In [2]: l=['s','t','a','k','','o','v','e','r']

In [3]: s='stack over'

In [4]: cmp(l, s)
Out[4]: -1

In [5]: cmp(''.join(l), s)
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: ''.join(l)
Out[6]: 'stakover'

In [7]: cmp(l, list(s))
Out[7]: 1
```